# How to push numbers into an array every time a function runs a la [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc...]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
const p1Wins = [];

function raiseScore() {
  if(xWinMessage) {
    const p1Name = document.querySelector('.p1-name');
    p1Name.style.color = 'green';

    for(i = 0; i < p1Wins.length; i++) {
      p1Wins.push(i)
    }
    
    let p1Score = document.querySelector('.p1-score');
    p1Score = p1Wins
  }
}
```

Not sure what I'd need to do to make this work. If anyone could help that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work right now?

Comment: It's not pushing numbers into the array.

Comment: Are you running the `raiseScore` function?

Comment: And is there an error? Or is `xWinMessage` false? Or what? What is the *problem*?

Comment: @VLAZ no errors, the array is just empty.

Comment: What is the length of `p1Wins` (before your `for` loop) when you run your function?

Comment: How did you determine that? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: @dave I am running the raiseScore function. It's a tic tac toe game and every time there's three x's in a row, the raiseScore function is called.

Comment: @NickParsons 0 .

Comment: @VLAZ I console.logged p1Wins

Comment: @Andrew your `p1Wins` array only gets items added to it when your for loop runs (at least in the code that you're showing). If it has a length of 0, then no items will be added to it as your for loop won't run

Comment: OK, how many times do you think the loop `for(i = 0; i < 0; i++)` would be executed?

Comment: @NickParsons any idea what I'd put as the second parameter for the for loop then?

Comment: @Andrew it depends on how many numbers you want to add, but if you just want to add one number each time your function runs (and make it increment), then you can remove the `for` loop and instead create a global counter variable that you increment each time your function runs which you can also push into your array - a bit more context would be needed to see if this is the best approach for your problem though

Comment: @NickParsons awesome! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to add [1,2,3,etc] in that order. You could do somthing like this.

```js
 const p1Wins = [];
 
 const pushStep = () => p1Wins.push(p1Wins.length+1);
 
 // call in the function
 pushStep();
 pushStep();
 pushStep();
 
 console.log(p1Wins);
```